# Google Sign In Crashes If Declined

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm using a google sign-in and when the user clicks the button but, does not sign in with google (Clicking the button and then cancelling), the app crashes. I'm not sure why.

Here's the code behind my button:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let authentication = user.authentication {
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Problem at signing in with google with error : \(String(describing: error))")
            } else if error == nil {
                print("user successfully signed in through GOOGLE! uid:\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
                print("signed in")
                self.firebaseAuth(credential)

            }
        })
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

at this line:

```
if let authentication = user.authentication {
```

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash? What is the full error message of the crash?

Comment: I just updated but, The error I get is: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at this line: "if let authentication = user.authentication {"

Comment: @ATrueNovice you can check for error in start of function like if error != nil {return} . This way it won't go inside if let authentication = user.authentication, if error is there.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Because when I tried doing that, the app crashed when the button was tapped.

Comment: You are passing `nil` to the `user` parameter of your `sign(_:didSignInFor:withError:)` method.

Comment: @ATrueNovice i mean just above this line if let authentication = user.authentication call  if error != nil {return}. Is that also giving crash?

Comment: Wouldn't that place my authentication method within the if error != nil? How would my variables be recognized at that point?

Comment: @ATrueNovice It will just return you out of function if there is any error while getting logged in or even if you decline one , and will not call any other line of code inside that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a good sign of developer always check for values which you want to use.
like if you want to user `user` object then check `if user != nil` don't go with `if error == nil`.
Here is my code for google sign in with firebase. Hope it'll help you.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        if error != nil {
            // ...
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if user == nil {
                // ...
                return
            } else {
                print(user!.displayName ?? "")
                print(user!.email ?? "")
                print(user!.phoneNumber ?? "")
                // User is signed in
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see what you mean. I didn't have the error checking in place. Thanks Mrugesh!

Answer (score 0):

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, 
withError error: Error?) {
    if user == nil {
print("Error, user pressed cancel button")
    } else {
// Start your code here.......

    }
}
```